# How to serve web components app with an express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-component

I have a project where I try to serve an app based on Web Components.
The folder structure of the the project is as follows:

|-- index.html
|-- my-component-one.js
|-- mock-server.js
|-- package.json

When I start the project with

> node ./mock-server.js

and open this page on browser `http://127.0.0.1:8092/` it just cannot find the lit-element dependency inside node_modules.

[image]

If I run `curl http://127.0.0.1:8092/node_modules/lit-element/` I get this response:

[image]

Although I add the node_modules folder as a static folder in express(`server.use(express.static('node_modules'))`), it cannot reach the files within node_modules.

I put the codes below.

Can you figure out the problem here?

Thanks in advance.
Best,

index.html

```
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Web Component Test</title>
  <script src="./node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Component Trial</h1>
  <my-component-one></my-component-one>
  <script type="module" src="my-component-one.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my-component-one.js

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class MyComponentOne extends LitElement {

  render() {
    return html`
      <p>My Component One</p>
   `;
  }

}

customElements.define('my-component-one', MyComponentOne);
```

mock-server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const port = 8092;

const server = express();

server.listen(port);

server.use(express.static('node_modules'));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "web-componnet-test",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./mock-server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lit-element": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the listen call above like so:

```
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));

server.listen(port);
```

Also, it's not a good idea to change things inside `node_modules` -- that folder is typically reserved only for external dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not solving the problem. It still cannot find the lit-element module.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I switched to es-dev-server of web components  https://github.com/open-wc/open-wc/tree/master/packages/es-dev-server and now it works like a charm.

I found this package within the example repository of lit element starter project: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/lit-element-starter-js

Apparently, the browser fails to bind the node_modules and this server fixes that.

FYI.

Answer (score 0):

For [some reasons](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/871) (for example its dependency with **lit-html**) you cannot import **lit-element** directly from the `node_modules` directory. You'll need to bundle it (with Rollup, Webpack...)

If you don't want to use a packager, you can instead import **lit-element** and all its dependencies via a CDN:

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js?module'
```

---

Note that you test with **curl** didn't work for another reason. You should not use "node_modules" in the path, and add the Javascript file name. This should work (but not resolve the dependency issue.)

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8092/lit-element/lit-element.js
```